# How does openGL come to the formula F_depth and and is this the window viewport transformation

Tags: opengl, transformation

```
#point no.1
```

after transforming points via the projection matrix , we end up with the point in the range [-1,1],
but, in the depth testing chapter , the author mentions that
F_depth = 1/z-1/far /(1/near - 1/far) converts the *view space coordinates* i.e. z=z<sub>eye</sub> is transformed from [-1,1] to [0,1] .

[I've followed this thread](https://community.khronos.org/t/when-and-how-does-opengl-calculate-f-depth-depth-value/106086/19), and one of the members tell me that the formula `F_depth` is actually a composition for a series of steps done, and outlines this step:

```
    z_Clip = C*z_eye+D*W_eye
    w_Clip = -z_eye
    where C=-(f+n)/(f-n), D=-2fn/(f-n).
    Projective division:
    z_ndc = z_clip/w_clip
    Depth range:
    depth = a + (a-b)*(z_ndc+1)/2
    where glDepthRange(a,b) .
```

[I tried composing the formula](https://pasteboard.co/JjnUtwz.jpg) as he had suggested, but this is completely different from the `F_depth` formula given in [learnopenGL](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Depth-testing).

```
#point no. 2
```

Also another member tells me that [-1,1] to [0,1] is the window viewport transformation, which has a [different formula itself](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Viewport_transform).

So, all of this is not making any sense to me(*having 3 different formulas and explanations for the same thing that also for openGL*), I'll bullet the queries I have regarding these contradicting ideas:

- Is F_depth a composition of transformations from view space to window
  space.
- Are the depth range transformation and viewport transformation the
  same? Why do they have different forumulas(one in `Point no.1` and
  another in [this link](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Viewport_transform)
- How is the F_depth formula obtained? Or how is does the composition
  of transformations done to convert the world space point to [0,1]
  result in `F_depth`?

Comment: I just found out the derivation  this formula actually seems to be a composition directly from eye space to window coordinate directly. The author should had explained that.

Comment: No it is not. It is just an approximation

Comment: @Rabbid76 , um... I always doubt my understanding which only clear off after weeks. It may be that I am thinking that I understand something. Could you take a look at my derivation below?

Comment: I still need to stress a point here: "after transforming points via the projection matrix , we end up with the point in the range `[-1,1]`". no we do not. we also do not end up in the range `[-w,w]`. Clip space is infinite. The _viewing volume_ is just a chosen, finite sub-volume of that space, and that one is mapped to the `[-1,1]` NDC cube (by default in OpenGL at least, there are different conventions to chose from). However, between clip space and NDC lies not only the perspective divide, but also the _clipping_ itself.

Comment: Hence, specifying a formula which describes the transformation from clip or eye space to NDC or window space is only valid for points which lie in the viewing volume. If you use a perspective projection, you will get bogus results for points behind the "camera", and you will even get a division by zero for points in the camera plane - both cases which never occur during the rendering by the GPU because those cases are eliminated by the clipping before they get to the perspective divide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the answer of @horxCoder are missing some steps, which I want to clarify.

In the tutorial [LearnOpenGL - Depth testing](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Depth-testing) is claimed that the depth at claimed at [Perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) is

```
depth = (1/z - 1/n) / (1/f - 1/n)
```

where `z` is the distance to the point of view, `n` is the distance to the near plane and `f` is the distance to the far plane of the [Viewing frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum).

The question is why the depth of a fragment is given by the above formula?

---

The symmetrically perspective projection matrix is (see [OpenGL Projection Matrix](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html)):

```
1/(ta*a)  0      0              0
0         1/ta   0              0
0         0     -(f+n)/(f-n)   -2fn/(f-n)
0         0     -1              0
```

For the depth we are just interested in the `z` and `w` component. For an input vertex *(x_eye, y_eye, z_eye, w_eye)*, the clip space *z_clip* and *w_clip* components are computed by:

```
z_Clip = C * z_eye + D * W_eye
w_Clip = -z_eye
```

where

```
C = -(f+n) / (f-n)
D = -2fn / (f-n)
```

The normalized device space *z* coordinate is computed by a [Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide)

```
z_ndc = z_clip / w_clip
```

The normalized device space *z* coordinate is mapped to the depth range *[a, b]* (see [`glDepthRange`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDepthRange.xhtml)):

```
depth = a + (a-b) * (z_ndc+1)/2
```

When we assume tha the depth range is *[0, 1]* and the input vertex is a [Cartesian coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) *(x_eye, y_eye, z_eye, 1)*, this leads to the following:

```
             z_eye * -(f+n) / (f-n)  +  -2fn / (f-n)
depth  =  (------------------------------------------ + 1) / 2
                          -z_eye
```

And can be transformed

```
             -z_eye * (f+n)  -  2fn
depth  =  (-------------------------- + 1) / 2
               -z_eye  *  (f-n)
```

```
             -z_eye * (f+n)  -  2fn  +  -z_eye * (f-n)
depth  =  ---------------------------------------------
                      -z_eye  *  (f-n)  * 2
```

```
             -z_eye * (f+n+f-n)  -  2fn
depth  =  -------------------------------
               -z_eye  *  (f-n)  * 2
```

```
             -z_eye * f  -  fn           -f (n + z_eye)  
depth  =  -----------------------   =   ----------------
               -z_eye * (f-n)             z_eye (n - f)
```

Since the view space z axis points out of the viewport, the `z` distance from the point of view to the vertex is `z = -z_eye`. This leads to:

```
          f (n - z)        1/z - 1/n
depth  =  -----------  =  -----------
          z (n - f)        1/f - 1/n
```

Answer (score 1):

Details and possible discussion and credit can be [found here](https://community.khronos.org/t/when-and-how-does-opengl-calculate-f-depth-depth-value/106086/26) also a huge thanks to @Rabbit76, initial part [of the question was here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63084469/when-and-how-does-opengl-calculate-f-depthdepth-value)

The steps outlined how the transformation goes are:

```
    1.The projection transformation:
    zclip = Czeye+Dweye
    wclip = -zeye
    where C=-(f+n)/(f-n), D=-2fn/(f-n).
    2.Projective division:
    zNDC = zclip/wclip
    3.Depth range transformation:
    depth = a + (b-a)*(zNDC+1)/2
    where glDepthRange(a,b) .
```

so, start from step 3:
openGL uses a=0, b=1, so step 3 becomes:

```
[ zNDC+1 ]/2
```

substitue value from step 2:

```
[ zclip / wclip   +  1 ] /2
```

substitue value from step 1 and simplify you get:

```
[1 + n/zeye]/[1-n/f]
```

**Now** for the formula from learnopenGL:

```
F_depth = [1/zeye - 1/n] /[ 1/f - 1/n]
```

if zeye = -zye, we get:

```
-(zeye + n)/(n-f) * nf/[zeye *n]
```

simplifying we get the same:

```
[1 + n/zeye]/[1-n/f]
```

So, the formula goes directly from the eye coordinate directly to the window-viewport coordinates.
Also, the depth range transformation is the window-viewport transformation for the z coordinate.

Comment: @Rabbid76 , I thought I did it correctly.... I don't see mistakes, here's a GIMPed derivation: https://pasteboard.co/JjnUtwz.jpg