# My understanding on the projection matrix, perspective division, NDC and viewport transform

Tags: opengl, projection-matrix, ndc

I was quite confused on how the projection matrix worked so I researched and I discovered a few other things but after researching a few days, I just wanted to confirm my understanding is correct. I might use a few wrong terms but my brain was exhausted after writing this. A few topics I just researched briefly like screen coordinates and window transform so I didn’t write much about it and my knowledge might be incorrect. Is everything I’ve written here correct or mostly correct? Correct me on anything if I’m wrong.

**What does the projection matrix do?**

So the perspective projection matrix defines a frustum that is a truncated pyramid. Anything outside of that frustum/frustum range will be clipped. I'll get more on that later. The perspective projection matrix also adds perspective. To make the vertices follow the rules of perspective, the perspective projection matrix manipulates the vertex's w component (the homogenous component) depending on how far the vertex is from the viewer (the farther the vertex is, the higher the w coordinate will increase).

**Why and how does the w component make the world look perceptive?**

The w component makes the world look perceptive because in the perspective division (perspective division happens in the vertex post processing stage), when the x, y and z is divided by the w component, the vertex coordinate will be scaled smaller depending on how big the w component is. So essentially, the w component scales the object smaller the farther the object is.

Example:

Vertex position (1, 1, 2, 2).

Here, the vertex is 2 away from the viewer. In perspective division the x, y, and z will be divided by 2 because 2 is the w component.

(1/2, 1/2, 2/2) = (0.5, 0.5, 1).

As shown here, the vertex coordinate has been scaled by half.

**How does the projection matrix decide what will be clipped?**

The near and far plane are the limits of where the viewer can see (anything beyond the far plane and before the near plane will be clipped). Any coordinate will also have to go through a clipping check to see if it has to be clipped. The clipping check is checking whether the vertex coordinate is within a frustum range of -w to w.  If it is outside of that range, it will be clipped.

Let's say I have a vertex with a position of (2, 130, 90, 90).

x value is 2

y value is 130

z value is 90

w value is 90

This vertex must be within the range of -90 to 90. The x and z value is within the range but the y value goes beyond the range thus the vertex will be clipped.

So after the vertex shader is finished, the next step is vertex post processing. In vertex post processing the clipping happens and also perspective division happens where clip space is converted into NDC (normalized device coordinates). Also, viewport transform happens where NDC is converted to window space.

**What does perspective division do?**

Perspective division essentially divides the x, y, and z component of a vertex with the w component. Doing this actually does two things, converts the clip space to Normalized device coordinates and also add perspective by scaling the vertices.

**What is Normalized Device Coordinates?**
Normalized Device Coordinates is the coordinate system where all coordinates are condensed into an NDC box where each axis is in the range of -1 to +1.

After NDC is occurred, viewport transform happens where all the NDC coordinates are converted screen coordinates. NDC space will become window space.

If an NDC coordinate is (0.5, 0.5, 0.3), it will be mapped onto the window based on what the programmer provided in the function `glViewport`. If the viewport is 400x300, the NDC coordinate will be placed at pixel 200 on x axis and 150 on y axis.

Answer (score 0):

The perspective projection matrix does not decide what is clipped. After transforming a world coordinate with the projection, you get a clipspace coordinate. This is a [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). Base on this coordinate the [Rendering Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview) clips the scene. The clipping rule is *-w < x, y, z < w*. In the following process of the rendering pipeline, the clip space coordinates is transformed into the normalized device space by the perspective divide *(x, y, z)' = (x/w, y/w, z/w)*. This division by the *w* component gives the perspective effect. (See also [What exactly are eye space coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588860/what-exactly-are-eye-space-coordinates/61537327#61537327) and [Transform the modelMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008171/transform-the-modelmatrix/46008573#46008573))